# Transfer data from SQL table to iOS app using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm creating an iOS app that allows users to log into the application using credentials stored in a SQL database. I have a table named "a_Employee", which looks like this:

[a_Employee Table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sztP6.png)

To connect the database to my iOS app, I want to encode the php in JSON and grab that from the database.

In the employees.php script, I want to grab all the data in the a_Employee table, and encode that in JSON.

Here is the employees.php script:

```
<html>
<head> <meta charset=UTF-8> <title>Query PHP</title></head>
<body>
<?php
    print "Opened Service.php";
    // Set up the data source information
    $dsn = "";
    $username = '';
    $password = '';

    // Create connection to MySQL
    try {
            $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
            echo "Connected to ekepling";

            // Execute a query
            $results = $db->query('SELECT * a_Employee');
            //$results2 = $db->query('SELECT lname FROM a_Employee');

            $myArray = array(); // new empty array
            $tempArray = array(); //temp array
            echo "Got to after execute query";

            // Put the titles in an array
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {

                    echo "<tr>";
                    foreach($row as $cell)
                    echo "<td>$cell</td>";
                    echo "</tr>\n";

                    /*
                    $myArray[] = $row["fname"];
                    $userID = $row['user_id'];
                    $userName = $row['user_name'];
                    $fname = $row['fname'];
                    $lname = $row['lname']
                    $manager_id = $row['manager_id'];
                    $title = $row['title'];
                    $email = $row['email'];
                    $project = $row['project'];
                    $businessPhone = $row['business_phone'];
                    $jobTitle = $row['job_title'];
                    $department = $row['department'];
                    $bio = $row['bio'];
                    $company = $row['company'];
                    $officeLocationID = $row['office_location_id'];
                    $teamLeadID = $row['team_lead_id'];
                    $projectID = $row['project_id'];
                    $locationID = $row['location_id'];
                    $user_pass = $row['user_pass'];
                    $tempArray = $row;
                    array_push($myArray, $tempArray);
                    */
            }

            echo json_encode($myArray);
            echo "Got to after putting titles in array";
            // Display the titles with html format information
            foreach($myArray as $title)
            {
                    echo $title;
                    echo "\n<br/>\n";
            }

            echo "Got to print array contents";

            // Close the MySQL connection
            $results = null;
            $db = null;
    }

     catch (PDOException $e) {
            // If this fails and exception isn’t caught, traceback will reveal
            //username and password
            echo "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
            die();
    }
?>
</body> </html>
```

username, password and database values have been omitted. When i run this script, I am not displaying anything. How can i write the script such that the SELECT * FROM a_Employee statement grabs all of the data and encodes it into JSON?

Comment: It looks like you're passing the entire user list from the server to the ios app. Don't do that. Instead have the app pass the typed-in userid and password to the server, which should verify it and return a true/false value.

Comment: I was planning on using all of the data from the table to populate various functionalities of the application. I agree though, but think the easiest solution would be trying to figure out how to just load all of the data at once.

Comment: If you need a list of users for the app, sure that's fine -- but don't pass back all their passwords.

Comment: What needs to be changed in the script to do this? Im currently not getting any output on the webpage